# Starting Ionic application with Node JS v 4.6

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

I installed node.js 4.6.

And `npm install -g ionic` but ionic command does not works.

[image: here].

Comment: Have you installed Cordova?

Comment: Yes, but it does not work

Comment: Make sure your npm path is in PATH environment variables.

Comment: Cordova works but Ionic does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) as well. Run the following to install all the necessary tools

`npm install -g cordova ionic`

Then create an app with one of the start templates they offer if you wish:

`ionic start MyApp blank`

`ionic start MyApp tabs`

`ionic start MyApp sidemenu`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will check and revert

Answer (score 0):

I set environment variables with Ionic, it works now